# Uninstall ubuntu from Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04

i installed ubuntu 12.04 on my  windows 7 (in C DRIVE).i didnt create any partition..
But unfortunately i deleted ubuntu folder in c drive(remember NOT UNINSTALLED).so how should i remove ubuntu option on startup???thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I presume this means you used the wubi installer. (Not installing from a CD, but downloading a windows program to install it), to remove this just go to add/remove programs in the windows control panel, and select ubuntu (it might be called wubi, I can't quite remember), and click uninstall.